# I can't rsync to my phone

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, android, rsync

I have a strange issue, i can connect to my phone using ssh, I can navigate inside its storage but I can't rsync to it.

I use Ubuntu as OS in PC, I have an Android (5.0) not rooted phone, with SSHelper installed.

Connection with SSH always gives me positive results, but if I try to rsync it what I get is:

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]

I must admit that I can't understand why it doesn't work, I mean if the ssh tunneling wasn't working I could understand but since ssh tunneling works I don't know what to do.

The most frustrating thing is that I have another Android (4.4) phone with SSHelper installed where rsync works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you post what your rsync command looks like?

Comment: `sudo rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2223' /home/neil/Music 192.168.2.162:/storage/MicroSD/Android`.
I changed the default port from 2222 to 2223 on SSHelper.
192.168.2.162 is my phone ip address.
Then password is required both for my account on the machine and in the phone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is some help for you...

I recently enountered the same issue.  My approach was to do the `rsync` to the home directory of the SSHelper installation.  For me the command was

```
rsync -avz --no-perms --no-times --size-only --exclude=".*" ~/Dokumente/Musik/Alben/ nexus5x:Alben
```

Afterwards, I logged on to my phone an simply used `mv` to move the directory `Alben` to the default music folder `/storage/emulated/0/Music/` on my Android instance.